# How to take a screenshot from WKWebView with embedded video?

Tags: ios, uikit, wkwebview, metal

I want to take a screenshot from `WKWebView` that contains a playing video.  I've tried a lot of methods, they work well on the simulator, but can't capture the content of the video on the device. Video content cannot be cpatured on the device:

Simulator:
[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDZyG.png)

Device:
[Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZfvT.png)

---

I tried the following ways:

**CALayer#render**

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
if window == nil { return }

let layer = window!.layer
let screenRect = window!.screen.bounds
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size)
let ctx:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
layer.render(in: ctx)
self.screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

and

**UIView#drawHierarchy**

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
if window == nil { return }

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window!.frame.size, false, 0)
window!.drawHierarchy(in: window!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
self.screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

and

**WKWebView#takeSnapshot**

```
let config = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
config.rect = WKWebViewHolder.webView!.frame
config.afterScreenUpdates = false
webView.takeSnapshot(with: config, completionHandler: { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?) in
     if error != nil {
       return
     }
     self.screenShotImage = image
})
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to take the screenshot:

**Details**
Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1.
Xcode 10.2 (10E125) and 11.0 (11A420a), Swift 5.
Tested on iOS: 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

**Solution**

```
import UIKit

extension UIApplication {

    func getKeyWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return keyWindow
        }
    }

    func makeSnapshot() -> UIImage? { return getKeyWindow()?.layer.makeSnapshot() }
}


extension CALayer {
    func makeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        render(in: context)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return screenshot
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func makeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size)
            return renderer.image { _ in drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) }
        } else {
            return layer.makeSnapshot()
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(snapshotOf view: UIView) {
        guard let image = view.makeSnapshot(), let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
imageView.image = UIApplication.shared.makeSnapshot()

// or
imageView.image = view.makeSnapshot()

// or
imageView.image = view.layer.makeSnapshot()

// or
imageView.image = UIImage(snapshotOf: view)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work.  The video area is black, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZfvT.png